# Python plotting trigonometrical func

Tags: python, numpy, plot

I have a function 2*x*arcctg(x) - 1, and i try to plot it in Python:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi / 2)
y = 2 * x * np.cos(2 * x) / np.sin(2 * x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

but it's plot smthg like that:
[image: Wrong pic in python]
and when i plot it in wolfram it looks:

[image: Right plot in Wolfram]
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Well for starters, `arcctg(x)` is not `cos(2x)/sin(2x)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function should be:

```
2*x*arcctg(x) - 1
```

But `arcctg(x)` is not `cos(2x)/sin(2x)` (the expression you describe in your code). A `ctg` is the *co-tangens*, so `cos(x)/sin(x)`. So that means that `arcctg(x)` is `arctan(1/x)`.

So you can use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi / 2)
y = 2 * x * np.arctan(1/x) - 1
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

This produces the following plot:

[image: The plot of 2x arcctg(x) - 1]

Which matches with the plot in the question.

In case you want to make the plot look more than the one in Wolfram Alpha, you can like @MSeifert says, set the range from -pi/2 to pi/2, like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

x = np.linspace(-np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, 1000)
y = 2 * x * np.arctan(1/x) - 1
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

this then produces:

[image: plot with different bounds]

Comment: @MSeifert: because the OP imports `os`. So my guess is that later he/she saves the image. But in this case it indeed not relevant.

Comment: Ah, okay. Just another suggestion: `x = np.linspace(-np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, 10000)` would match the wolfram output more exactly and avoids the invalid value at `0` (at least as long as the number of points created by linspace is not odd)

Comment: @MSeifert: thanks. I've updated the answer with your suggestion :).